# read dates line by line from text file and store them in a dictionary java

Tags: java, file-handling

I have a text file of ID numbers and dates in this format:

```
ID  Date
1   14/03/2011
2   06/03/2013
3   25/02/2013
4   28/01/2013
5   13/07/2011
6   13/03/2011
7   01/10/2012
8   09/10/2012
```

I need to read this txt file and store each date in a dictionary like a hashmap or something in the  format. Also, it would be preferable if the dates are in the `DATE` data type and not String.
I tried to do it myself but I am a beginner in JAVA and I couldn't get it done. 
Thanks in advance for any help

This is what I've tried till now. I haven't used a dictionary, I tried to put the dates in an ArrayList and for some reason, it reads only every alternate line from the file so half the dates are missing.

```
static Date[] list = new Date[59400];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File file = new File("dates.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        String readLine = "";

        int i =0;
        while ((readLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String s = bufferedReader.readLine();
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(s);
            System.out.println(s+","+i);
            i++;
        }
        fileReader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It'd be helpful you post what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go through these two pages - 
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Search before posting. The issues in this Question have been addressed many many time already on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following function.

```
public static void parseFile() throws IOException, ParseException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("inputFileName.txt")));
    Map<Integer, Date> integerDateMap = new HashMap<>(); // Map to put data
    SimpleDateFormat sdfmt2= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); // date format
    String line = null;
    line = bufferedReader.readLine(); // neglect first line
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
         String[] split = line.split("   ");
         integerDateMap.put(Integer.parseInt(split[0]),sdfmt2.parse(split[1]));
    }
    System.out.println(integerDateMap); // print to check
}
```

Comment: Doing someone's homework for them doesn't help them ... in the long run.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is exactly what i need

Comment: This Answer is outmoded, using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: Wanted to give as basic syntax as possible and closer to what he has tried out. I know this is out-moded!!!

Answer (score 1):

> ....  for some reason, it reads only every alternate line from the file so half the dates are missing.

Look at these two lines from your code:

```
    while ((readLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String s = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

First one reads a line of text into `readLine`.

Second one reads the next line into `s`.

The alternate lines that you read into `readLine` are never used.

---

Can I recommend that you take the time to read this article:

- [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.